# How to fix "Parallel Arrays Must Have Same Length" error for chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, array

I'm using a transect with two types of data to collect temperature and aerosol index on Google Earth Engine. I want to print a line chart using multiple dates, but I keep getting two error listings:

> Array (Error) Dictionary.toArray: Parallel arrays must have the same
> length.  Error generating chart: Dictionary.toArray: Parallel arrays
> must have the same length.

This is the section of the code which is probably the problem.

```
var distance = startingPoint.distance(500000);    
var image =   distance.addBands(summer2018).addBands(winter2018).addBands(summer2019).addBands(winter2019).addBands(aerosum2018).addBands(aerowin2018).addBands(aerosum2019).addBands(aerowin2019);  
// Extract band values along the transect line.  
var array = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.toList(), transect, 1000)  
                 .toArray(image.bandNames());  
                 print (array, 'array');  

// Sort points along the transect by their distance from the starting point.  
var distances = array.slice(0,0,1);  
array = array.sort(distances);  

// Create arrays for charting.  
var aerosoltemp = array.slice(0,1);  // For the Y axis.  
// Project distance slice to create a 1-D array for x-axis values.  
var distance = array.slice(0,0,1).project([1]);  

// Generate and style the chart.  
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(aerosoltemp, 1, distance)  
    .setChartType('LineChart')  
    .setSeriesNames(['Summer 2018','Winter 2018','Summer 2019','Winter 2019', 'Aero Summer 2018', 'Aero Winter 2018', 'Aero Summer 2019', 'Aero Winter 2019'])
    .setOptions({  
      title: 'Air Pollution and Temperatures Along Indonesia Transect',  
      vAxes: {  
        0: {  
          title: 'Average Seasonal Temperature (Fahrenheit)'  
        },  
        1: {  
          title: 'Aerosol Index',  
          baselineColor: 'transparent'  
        }  
      },  
      hAxis: {  
        title: 'Distance from Jambi (m)'  
      },  
      interpolateNulls: true,  
      pointSize: 0,  
      lineWidth: 1,  
      // My chart has two Y axes: one for temperature and one for air pollution.  
      // The Visualization API allows us to assign each series to a specific  
      // Y axis, which we do here:  
      series: {  
        0: {targetAxisIndex: 1},  
        1: {targetAxisIndex: 0},  
        2: {targetAxisIndex: 0}  
               }  
      });  
      
print(chart);  
Map.setCenter(103.61, -1.58);  
Map.addLayer(aerosol, {min: -1, max: 2.0},'pollution');  
Map.addLayer(transect, {color: 'blue'},'transect');
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact error text with line number (and comment the line where it occurs, if you can)

Comment: Since you are only sharing a subset of your script, we can't reproduce the error to help debug - please share the whole script. However, it is likely that the `aerosoltemp` and `distance` do not have the same number of rows. Double check your array slicing logic and print the dimensions of the chart inputs to make sure they match on row length.